# How to run smart contract function with web3 and/or Moralis?

Tags: javascript, web3js, moralis

I have all of the parameters and options. Just having trouble on how to call the function with JavaScript. Here's where I'm at right now.

```
<body>
<script>
    
    const web3 = await Moralis.enableWeb3();

    async function mintToken() {
        const ABI = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_VRFCoordinator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_LinkToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"_keyhash","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_fee","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"approved","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"ApprovalForAll","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"string","name":"tokenURI","type":"string"}],"name":"CreatedRandomSVG","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"randomNumber","type":"uint256"}],"name":"CreatedUnfinishedRandomSVG","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes32","name":"requestId","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"requestedRandomSVG","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"_bytes32","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"bytes32ToString","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"colors","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"create","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"requestId","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"finishMint","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"imageURI","type":"string"}],"name":"formatTokenURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_randomness","type":"uint256"}],"name":"generatePath","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"pathSvg","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_randomness","type":"uint256"}],"name":"generatePathCommand","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"pathCommand","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_randomness","type":"uint256"}],"name":"generateSVG","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"finalSvg","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getApproved","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"}],"name":"isApprovedForAll","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"maxNumberOfPathCommands","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"maxNumberOfPaths","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ownerOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"pathCommands","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"requestId","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"randomness","type":"uint256"}],"name":"rawFulfillRandomness","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"requestIdToSender","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"requestIdToTokenId","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"setApprovalForAll","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"size","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"interfaceId","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"svg","type":"string"}],"name":"svgToImageURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"tokenCounter","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenIdToRandomNumber","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"}];
    
        const options = {
            contractAddress: "0xC677b7A473aAA91B3c6a1D9433f5943AF0b04B11",
            functionName: "create",
            abi: ABI,
            params: {
            },
        };
        await Moralis.executeFunction(options);
        console.log("Starting mint process");
        
          .catch(function (error) {
            console(error);
          });
    }

    document.getElementById("mint_SoftHands").onclick = mintToken;
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are 2 ways to achieve that:

1. using Moralis.Web3API.native.runContractFunction
2. using web3.eth.Contract object

About the first approach you can learn https://docs.moralis.io/moralis-server/web3-sdk/native

And code for the second should look something like this:

```
let web3 = await Moralis.Web3.enable();
let accounts = new web3.eth.getAccounts();
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT_ABI,CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
contract.methods.mint_function_name(param1, param2).send({from:accounts[0],value:PRICE_ETH});
```